# How do I send the stdout of a command to an Expect input?

Tags: shell-script, expect

I want to write a shell + expect script that auto-fills my passwords via the LastPass CLI utility `lpass`.  I'm not sure how to accomplish sending the password returned by `lpass` to the password input in an expect script.

The expect script so far looks something like:

```
# The beginning isn't important
expect -exact "\r
Please enter your username and password.\r
Username:"
send -- "my-username\r"
expect -exact "my-username\r
Password:"
send -- $(lpass show --password service\ im\ connecting\ to)
expect -exact "\r
# The rest of the expect script follows
```

I'm not sure how the bit in the $(...) should actually be written...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use `exec` function in `expect` script to get the same behavior as `$(...)` does in shell

See example below:
Let use external program `4expect.sh` below that we will feed with out `expect` script:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Test program : let set filename as "4expect.sh"
# in the same directory where expect script will work

echo; read -p 'question: ' answer
echo "Got answer:>${answer}<"
```

And here our `expect` script that will wait for "question" from external program and feed it with total files in current directory (get output of external programs `ls` and `egrep`) that will be used by `expect`'s `send`:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

spawn -noecho ./4expect.sh
expect -re "question" { send -- [exec ls -la . | egrep "^total" ]\r }
interact

puts "\nDone.\n"
exit
```

Comment: The problem isn't getting lpass to return the password to stdout - the lpass command I gave in the example does that.  It's how to capture that stdout and `send` it in an expect script.  I haven't found that $(...) in expect scripts works as it does in regular shell scripting.

Comment: Ohh, man... I'm really sorry, I completely misunderstood your question. I removed my previous answer since it was irrelevant and replaced it with correct answer. Duh...

Comment: Couple with this to handle things like your SUDO pass.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/681928/how-can-i-make-an-expect-script-prompt-for-a-password.  Now I can automate all my logins.  fantastic!